# Processing output nothing using gouraud shading

Tags: glsl, processing, shader, gouraud

sorry, I am a new on opengl es and processing
below processing and shaders output only background

PShader Gouraud,Phong;

```java
rocket = loadShape("rocket.obj");
rocket.setFill(color(800, 0, 0));
Gouraud= loadShader("gouraudfragment.glsl","gouraudvertex.glsl");
Phong= loadShader("phongfragment.glsl","phongvertex.glsl");
```

```java
background(0);

pushMatrix();
shader(Gouraud);
translate(130,height/2.0);
rotateY(rc);
rotateX(0.4);
noStroke();
fill(#800080);
box(100);

rc+=(0.02+speedCube);
rc*=dirCube;
popMatrix();

pushMatrix();
shader(Gouraud);
translate(width/2, height/2 + 100, -200);
rotateZ(PI);
rotateY(rr);
shape(rocket,100,100);

rr +=( 0.02+speedRocket);
rr*=dirRocket;
popMatrix();
```

vertex shader

```c
varying vec3 N;
varying vec3 v;
varying vec4 diffuse;
varying vec4 spec;
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
uniform mat4 modelview;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;
uniform vec4 lightPosition;
uniform vec3 lightAmbient;
uniform vec3 lightDiffuse;
uniform vec3 lightSpecular;
uniform float SpecularPower;

void main()
{
   vec4 diffuse;
   vec4 spec;
   vec4 ambient;

   v = vec3(modelview * position);
   N = normalize(normalMatrix * normal);
   gl_Position = projectionMatrix * position;  

   vec3 L = normalize(lightPosition.xyz - v);
   vec3 E = normalize(-v);
   vec3 R = normalize(reflect(-L,N)); 

   ambient = vec4(lightAmbient,100.0);
   diffuse = vec4(clamp( lightDiffuse * max(dot(N,L), 0.0)  , 0.0, 1.0 ) ,100.0);
   spec = vec4(clamp (lightSpecular * pow(max(dot(R,E),0.0),0.3*SpecularPower) , 0.0, 1.0 ),100.0);

   color = ambient + diffuse + spec;
}
```

fragment shader

```c
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

please help!
before apply gouraud shading
[image]

after apply gouraud shading
[image: after Gouraud]

The prcessing load the obj and the draw a cube and apply a gouraud shader, but after that only backgroud are shown, the obj loaded and cube is gone. nothing shown!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the shader doesn't even compile and link. The vertex shader has 1 `varying` output (`color`), so the framgent shader needs the input `varying vec4 color;`.

```c
varying vec4 color;
```

When you set the clip space position, then the vertex coordinate has to be transformed by the model view and projection matrix:

```c
gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelview * position;
```

The types specifications of `v` and `N` are missing and the types of `ambient`, `diffuse` and `spec` are `vec4` rather than `vec3`.

Vertex shader:

```c
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec3 normal;

varying vec4 color;

uniform mat4 modelview;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;
uniform vec4 lightPosition;
uniform vec3 lightAmbient;
uniform vec3 lightDiffuse;
uniform vec3 lightSpecular;
uniform float SpecularPower;

void main()
{
   vec3 v      = vec3(modelview * position);
   vec3 N      = normalize(normalMatrix * normal);
   gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelview * position;  

   vec3 L = normalize(lightPosition.xyz - v);
   vec3 E = normalize(-v);
   vec3 R = normalize(reflect(-L,N)); 

   vec4 ambient = vec4(lightAmbient,100.0);
   vec4 diffuse = vec4(clamp( lightDiffuse * max(dot(N,L), 0.0)  , 0.0, 1.0 ) ,100.0);
   vec4 spec = vec4(clamp (lightSpecular * pow(max(dot(R,E),0.0),0.3*SpecularPower) , 0.0, 1.0 ),100.0);

   color = ambient + diffuse + spec;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```c
varying vec4 color;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Of course you have to set at least an ambient light source [`ambientLight()`](https://processing.org/reference/ambientLight_.html). 
You can use a [`directionalLight()`](https://processing.org/reference/directionalLight_.html), [`pointLight()`](https://processing.org/reference/pointLight_.html) or [`spotLight()`](https://processing.org/reference/spotLight_.html), too.
But note, your shader can handle 1 light source only. More the 1 light source would gain

> OpenGL error 1282 at top endDraw(): invalid operation

If you want to use more than 1 light source then you would have to use uniform arrays int the vertex shader for `lightPosition`, `lightAmbient`, `lightDiffuse`, and `lightSpecular`. See [Types of shaders in Processing](https://processing.org/tutorials/pshader/)(https://processing.org/tutorials/pshader/)